HTTP Request using TLS 1.3 fails in .NET only (Token supplied is invalid)
A simple HTTP GET request to a particular website, using TLS 1.3, fails in .NET with Win32Exception "The token supplied to the function is invalid".
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
await httpClient.GetAsync("https://some-website.tld");

Using a webbrowser (MS Edge), or performing the same request using Java or Python works fine. Confirmed using Wireshark that the connection is indeed using TLS 1.3. Other websites using TLS 1.3 also works fine. The certificate algorithm is sha384ECDSA.
Tried intercepting the certificate validation using the ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback, but it is never executed.
Changing the protocol to TLS 1.2 by setting SslProtocols on HttpClientHandler makes the request complete succesfully (confirmed using TLS 1.2 using Wireshark).
Validated the server certificate using Verify on X509Certificate2, and considering that the connection is established successfully using a browser or other programming languages suggests that the certificate itself is not the problem.
I suspect it has something to do with the underlying implementation used by .NET (SCHANNEL?). I cannot find any further details on the exception.
.NET version 8 on Windows 11 - tried on several machines and different networks.
Any suggestions or further troubleshooting steps ?

Can you check all the algos used in the Chain of Certificates? Maybe the issuer certificates are problematic not yours directly.

Certificates are used for lots of different purposes.  You have a TLS certificate and an Authentication Certificate.  TLS is run to make a secure connection between client and server.  Toke is part of the Authentication.  So TLS is working.  Authentication is not working.  I think there is a missing http header.  Try making connection with Postman.  Then check the Postman Control Panel to get entire HTTP Request which will contain all the HTTP header.  Then add missing header to the HTTP Client.

Tokens are usually part of a two step authentication.  First step is to get token.  Second step is to use token in a request.  So you need to make two requests.

If you use http/2 during TLS 1.3 communications with Client Certificates, pls test if it works with 'Client Certificates' disabled if applicable, or test with TLS 1.3 and http 1.1. There are some issues w/ http/2 and client certificate authentication. Ref: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc8740/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis#when-is-http2-not-supported

@Ralf All certificates in the chain use sha384ECDSA.

@jdweng Based on the error message, I understand your comment, but I don't think this is the issue. When performing the request in a browser, Postman, or using other programming languages, even with no client authentication, the server replies with 200 OK, and an HTML body. No additional headers are sent using Postman.

@ErkinD39 Tried setting DefaultRequestVersion = new Version(1, 1) and DefaultVersionPolicy = HttpVersionPolicy.RequestVersionOrLower on the HttpClient - same error. Also, while client certificate is to be used, it isn't specified at the moment, but the server is expected to return 200 OK with an HTML response anyway, as mentioned in previous comment. (HTML saying auth required). However the connection fails before receiving the response, and the ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback is never hit, so I believe the connection is never succesfully established.

If server software does not have any bugs then 200 OK indicates the connection completed (not TLS errors) and the server responded without any errors.  Normally this means the query did not return any data from the database.  You do not have any errors. Check the content length (size of the data in the body of the response).  Maybe the code is not reading the body properly.  My opinion the response is good and you are just having issues reading the body.

@jdweng The exception occurs with a blank C# project, and only the two lines of code in the original question. The method does not return - there is no 200 OK - only using other clients, like a browser or Postman. Wireshark confirms that the communication stops early.

Schannel logging on Windows client/server can be increased via registry as defined in the link  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/enable-schannel-event-logging. ( 7 all events)  Also CAPI2 logs can be enabled for other details. As far as I understand the issue is confined to .NET httpclient class and TLS 1.3 relation.

@ErkinD39 Can't see anything related in CAPI2 logs, but the SCHANNEL log shows fatal alert code 40 (handshake_failure). That suggests missing overlap between server and client parameters. I don't know how to see further details about the exchanged parameters though. While it does only happen from .NET HttpClient, the exception is a Win32Exception which I believe means it happens outside .NET context.

Sha384 is only TLS 1.2 (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).  Make sure when TLS 1.3 is working there is no retries in WireShark and TLS 1.2 is really being used.

@jdweng Only in relation to HMAC as far as I can see. Also then it shouldn't work with other clients, and there are no retries - it remains on TLS 1.3 according to Wireshark.

You need to read RFC 8446 para 1.3 and 4.1.3  TLS 1.3 has a down grade option for TLS 1.2.  Looks like Net doesn't implement the downgrade mode.  See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446

Alert 40 handshake_failure: "Indicates that the sender was unable to negotiate an acceptable set of security parameters given the options available. This is a fatal error."  Do you use a proxy while connecting with a browser? Does httpclient have a default proxy set?

@ErkinD39 : RFC 8740 is for HTTP/2.  I don't see anything in posting implying HTTP/2.  I think the issue is with the down grade option for TLS 1.3 in RFC 8446 which doesn't look like Net implements.  See my previous comment.

@jdweng I checked the last bytes of the Random value in the Server Hello message, and they do not match the sequence described in section 4.1.3. Also, the documentation of the server it's connecting to says it is TLS 1.3 compatible.

@ErkinD39 No, there should be no proxy involved. Also tried from a different computer on a different network. Also tried from within a Windows Sandbox to get a clean environment. Same issue.

Do you have an IIS 10 installed PC/server (W11/W2022)  in your environment? If you can run the same code against an IIS website, both sides of the communication can be traced for TLS1.3 traffic.  In this scenario as far as I see remote site logs can not be obtained, so only one side is investigated. If your code encounters the same TL S 1.3 handshake problem then  .NET httpclient class is the responsible I think.

@ErkinD39 The server is managed by a 3rd party. Haven't tried setting up a server with TLS 1.3 for testing, but since the .NET Client works with other websites using TLS 1.3, I don't think TLS 1.3 is the issue. It's something very specific to the targeted site, but I don't know what to more to look for. Can't see any significant differences.

@ajins, you may also chk the website using curl tool and forcing TLS 1.3 only. If you can connect succesfully pls note the http versions, key length, encyrption algorithms.

@ErkinD39 Just tried using curl.exe (Not the Invoke-WebRequest alias), with the --tlsv1.3 option, as well as verbose and trace. It actually fails with the same error, although there is no further details besides that it uses HTTP/1.1. So .NET is not the issue. The error output is: "schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN (0x80090308) - The token supplied to the function is invalid"

@ErkinD39 Actually, just tried downloading a windows build from the curl website (as opposed to the Microsoft provided one which uses SCHANNEL https://curl.se/windows/microsoft.html). With that one, the request succeeds, so the problem must be related to SCHANNEL. Details from the curl output: "SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 / [blank] / UNDEF", "ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.", "Public key type ? (384/192 Bits/secBits), signed using ecdsa-with-SHA384", "using HTTP/1.x"

On a linux build, the corresponding outputs are:
"SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 / x25519 / id-ecPublicKey",
"ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.",
"Public key type EC/secp384r1 (384/192 Bits/secBits), signed using ecdsa-with-SHA384",
"using HTTP/1.x".
Also after Server hello, the next line on linux is
"TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8)",
where on windows build it says
"TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8)".

I have reproduced alert 40 on IIS. For the website I have disabled http2, http3, legacy TLS, TLS 1.3, then I ran curl forcing TLS 1.3 and Schannel events say "A fatal alert was generated and sent to the remote endpoin`t. This may result in termination of the connection. The TLS protocol defined fatal alert code is 40." This is an issue on the server side, if they are using IIS 10, they should set "Ignore Client Certificates" on SSL settings, and they should NOT disable http2,http3, TLS 1.3. Their events are more important. Your logs do not show that requests succeed, there are lots of "?" mark

@ErkinD39 Their documentation clearly says TLS 1.3 is supported. Yes, there are a lot of "?" marks, which is odd, but I do now get a HTTP Request and Response, including body with expected content.
